# Total Orders on Dashboard

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I am trying to get the data of dashboard only for previous month. Say for example I want to change the total orders query for dashboard, I can edit the query of getTotalOrders() in admin\model\sale\order.php accordingly. I was wondering if the same method is used for any other module then it would mess up the data. So instead of editing that method I created my own method say getPreviousMonthTotalOrders(), but I can't figure out how to call this method for dashboard data instead of getTotalOrders().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the controller admin\controller\common\dashboard.php there is this line:

```
$output = $this->load->controller('extension/dashboard/' . $code . '/dashboard');
```

So I checked admin\controller\extension\dashboard\order.php

and changed

```
$order_total = $this->model_sale_order->getTotalOrders();
```

to

```
$order_total = $this->model_sale_order->getPreviousMonthTotalOrders();
```